# Pandas group-by, filter, and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'id':[1,2,3,4,3,3,1,6], 'type':['t2','t1','t2','t2','t3','t3','t4','t3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The goal is to get a dataframe that is grouped by id and has the `nunique` of each type per group.

I thought this would resolve it but it does not seem to work:

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'type':pd.Series.nunique()})
```

Comment: Remove the `()` from `nunique`, as you want to pass a reference to the function, not to call it. `df.groupby(by='id').agg(pd.Series.nunique)` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @dnswlt - i new it was an easy one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a bit more simply by just accessing the `type` SeriesGroupBy first.

```
>>> df.groupby('id').type.nunique()
id
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    1
6    1
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, your current approach does not work as [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) expects a function object which it can call (`nunique`), not an actual function call attempt as you have with `nunique()` .